# How to format axis in Python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib

I'd like to format xaxis as dd:mm HH:MM. My code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.plot('a', "r.",data=xxx, markersize=1.5)
plt.axis(["2017-04-24 0:00", "2017-04-24 23:59", 0, 400])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

My output format is: dd:mm HH. How can I fix it? I don't have any idea;/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a date formatter to your axis:

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

# your plot set-up code...
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%m:%d %H:%M"))
# etc.
```